# How to use Material-UI Autocomplete component to select multiple options and add new options?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

**goal**

I have a multiple field that:

1. we can select users present in the autocompletion (a list that I retrieve via API)
2. We can enter the names of new users that we separate them with a comma

For that, I therefore need to retrieve the value of ***value*** and ***inputValue***. For ***value***, there is no problem but for ***inputValue***, there is something that I do not understand

**problem**

When I modify the value of ***inputValue*** in *onInputChange*, its state is modified and reseted [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEgr3.png)

**information**

I base on [the example that material UI offers](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#controllable-states)

[Code in Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-react-material-ui-forked-lgx97?file=/src/AutocompleteControlled.tsx:0-1491)

Code

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const userList: User[] = [
  { id: 1, name: "name 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "name 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "name 3" }
];

export default function AutocompleteControlled() {

  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState<number[]>([]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        value={userList.filter((el) => users.includes(el.id))}
        onChange={(event: any, newValue: User[]) => {
          setUsers(newValue.map((el) => el.id));
        }}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event: any, newInputValue: string) => {
          console.log("newInputValue", newInputValue);
          setInputValue(newInputValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={userList}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" variant="outlined" />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

All comments are welcome :)

Comment: Whats the point of this `value={userList.filter((el) => users.includes(el.id))}`?

Comment: To retrieve the lists of selected users because the type of value is **User**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want to enable multi selection, and allow the user to enter any arbitrary value in the textbox. Therefore you can use the `Autocomplete` component with the `freesolo` prop set to true, so the textbox can contain any arbitrary value.

[This](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values) is the Material-UI example closest to your use case.

We will use a controlled component, so you can control its behavior with the `value` and `onChange` props. Check the code below.

You can select from the pre-populated items, or you can enter any arbitrary value and press enter, and a chip will be added to the component, and the value will be added to the array in the state.

Currently `value` is an array of the names but you can set it to the `id`s or whatever you want.

Try this code:

```
import React from "react";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { createStyles, makeStyles, Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      width: 500,
      "& > * + *": {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
      },
    },
  })
);

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const userList: User[] = [
  { id: 1, name: "name 1" },
  { id: 2, name: "name 2" },
  { id: 3, name: "name 3" },
  { id: 4, name: "name 4" },
  { id: 5, name: "name 5" },
];

export default function AutocompleteControlled() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<any>([userList[0].name]);

  console.log("value: ", value);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        multiple
        id="tags-filled"
        options={userList.map((option) => option.name)}
        freeSolo
        renderTags={(value: string[], getTagProps) =>
          value.map((option: string, index: number) => (
            <Chip
              variant="outlined"
              label={option}
              {...getTagProps({ index })}
            />
          ))
        }
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="filled"
            label="Users"
            placeholder="Search"
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how it looks, the controlled value is logged to the console.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: why are using index and not id? how do you use the ID from Users[] ?

Comment: I didn't need the multiple value part.. but thanks to you I noticed that on enter the onchange is called.. Normally people would just type and move away from the field.. I added an onBlur to update the value.